# belongs_to many Situation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-key-relationship, belongs-to, has-one

Here is the situation:

> Model : Account
>   has_one servicelist
>
> Model: Servicelist  ( has foreign key as 'account_id' & 'videoservice_id')
>   belongs_to Account
>   belongs_to videoservice.
>
> Model : videoservice.
>   has_one servicelist.

When I save Account instance `X`. It saves `account_id` from `X.id`.

then later after some time if the Account `X` wants to start using the videoservice.
How do I save the `videoservice.id` into `Servicelist.videoservice_id (fk)` where `Servicelist.account_id(fk) == X.id` ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is `has_one :through => servicelists`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89908/how-does-has-one-through-work) on how to use  `:through`.